# Python - Scrape Only Bold Words

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am working on a research project and as a part of it I need to scrape an e-book for all of the bold words. I am new to python and programming in general (please bear with me). I have reviewed various Beautiful Soup tutorials and I have a decent handle on extracting text from a webpage, but I cannot figure out how to just target words with the `<strong>` or `<b>` tag. I have been practicing with a random wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Scottish_war_(1650%E2%80%931652) as I try to get better at this, but at this point I feel like I have hit a wall.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided what you have achieved so far.

Comment: There are libraries for parsing html.  Don't make me post a link to the regexp question.

Comment: I assume the e-books are in HTML format?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you get the bold words from that wikipedia page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Scottish_war_(1650%E2%80%931652)')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

bold_words = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.select('b')]
print(bold_words)
```

Which returns a list:
`['Bishops Wars', 'First English Civil War', 'Second English Civil War', 'Anglo-Scottish war (1650–1652)', "Glencairn's rising", 'Scotland', 'England', ...]`

If your e-book is in html format, you just do: `soup = BeautifulSoup('ebook_html_object', 'html.parser')`